# SFTP with public and private keys

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, private-key

I want to use private and public keys for access to the SFTP server, instead of a username/password mechanism. SFTP server should be available only for a specific user that can log in from whatever IP address she wants. I found that it can be done using `ssh-keygen`. Can you please write the correct steps, in order not to mix/delete the existing SSH keys and permissions (SFTP is also on port 22)?

Edit:
I followed the process described at https://www.jscape.com/blog/setting-up-sftp-public-key-authentication-command-line. I do not know how to separate SFTP private and public keys from SSH certificates, and how to allow specific user from any IP address to connect using keys.

Comment: SuperUser is not a consultancy service. We expect a certain level of effort. What have you tried yourself and what failed there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: either use `ssh-copy-id` as instructed, in any case `id_rsa` is private part (to be kept localy) and `id_rsa.pud` is public to be appended to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on remote_account@remote_host